# How to display intermediate result in a VB calculator program

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I am writing a simple Visual Basic four function calculator (add, subtract, multiply, and divide) application and I want to display an intermediate result when an operator is pressed.

The Windows form that I have created contains buttons, therefore inputs are only required via mouse clicks on the GUI (no keyboard input)

As defined in the requirements, a complete "problem" will be entered according to the following sequence rules:

1. A number, followed by
2. An operator key, followed by
3. Another number, followed by
4. Optionally repeat to step 2 (displaying intermediate result as the operator is pressed), or the equals button.

I understand that the changes need to be made in the operator click_events to meet this requirement, but I have no idea how to do it.

here is the code for the add, subtract, multiply, divide, and equals button

```
Dim txtNumber As String
Dim variable1 As Decimal
Dim variable2 As Decimal
Dim answerResult As Decimal
Dim arithmeticProcess As String

 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    If answerResult <> 0 Then
        answerResult = variable1 + variable2
        variable1 = CDec(lblDisplay.Text)
        lblDisplay.Text = ""
        arithmeticProcess = "+"
    Else
        variable1 = CDec(lblDisplay.Text)
        lblDisplay.Text = ""
        arithmeticProcess = "+"
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub btnSubtract_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
    variable1 = CDec(lblDisplay.Text)
    lblDisplay.Text = ""
    arithmeticProcess = "-"
End Sub

Private Sub btnMultiply_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMultiply.Click
    variable1 = CDec(lblDisplay.Text)
    lblDisplay.Text = ""
    arithmeticProcess = "*"
End Sub

Private Sub btnDivide_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDivide.Click
    variable1 = CDec(lblDisplay.Text)
    lblDisplay.Text = ""
    arithmeticProcess = "/"
End Sub

Private Sub btnEqual_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEqual.Click
    variable2 = lblDisplay.Text
    If arithmeticProcess = "+" Then
        answerResult = variable1 + variable2
    ElseIf arithmeticProcess = "-" Then
        answerResult = variable1 - variable2
    ElseIf arithmeticProcess = "*" Then
        answerResult = variable1 * variable2
    Else
        answerResult = variable1 / variable2
    End If

    answerResult = Math.Round(answerResult, 9)
    Select Case answerResult
        Case Is > 4000000000
            MessageBox.Show("The answer is too large to be displayed.")
            variable1 = 0
            variable2 = 0
            lblDisplay.Text = ""
        Case Is < -4000000000
            MessageBox.Show("The answer is too small to be displayed.")
            variable1 = 0
            variable2 = 0
            lblDisplay.Text = ""
        Case Else
            lblDisplay.Text = CStr(answerResult)
    End Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I need to politely point out that I think you're going to run into issues with your logic as you continue with this program, but figuring that out is part of the fun of programming. You may want to step back and flow-chart your calculator application, and then get back into it.

Now, what does the code for your number buttons (0-9) look like, specifically, how do you know if the user is typing `variable1` or `variable2`? Assuming you're performing that operation in a 'logical' way, here's what I would do:

1. `Dim variable1 As Decimal = 0` to give your numbers a 'default value' of sorts, and do the same for `variable2`.
2. Pull the code out of `btnEqual_Click` and put it in its own method, let's call it `Public Sub DoMaths()`, then simply put `DoMaths()` in `btnEqual_Click(...)`.
3. For every 'arithmeticProcess' button (plus, minus, ...) you are also going to call `DoMaths()` after doing what you already are.

Now here's the tricky part. You'll have to carefully track which `variableX` you're displaying on the screen at a given time.

4. In `DoMaths()`, after performing your calculations, you're going to want to move the value of `answerResult` to `variable1`, and reset `variable2` to zero. I would put this at the end of your `Case Else` block.

   ```
   Case Else
       lblDisplay.Text = CStr(answerResult)
       variable1 = answerResult
       variable2 = 0
   ```

This puts you back to a state where you would be if the user had just entered in their first number (`variable1`) and is ready to press the next arithmetic operator key.

---

**Edit**, in response to your digit button code:

First, a suggestion: `txtNumber += "1"` should really be `txtNumber &= "1"`. Although there are arguments otherwise, plus is for adding numbers, ampersand is for concatenating two strings.

Second, in order to achieve intermediate calculations like you desire, you're going to have to keep track of whether or not a "final calculation" (with the Equals key) has been performed. I suggest doing this by using your `variable1`. When any Plus/Minus/Equals/etc.. button is pressed, you can [generally] assume there is nothing to be done, so long as `variable1` is zero.

1. The user types in a number, then presses an arithmetic key. You store the arithmetic operator (as you already are) and move the number to `variable1`.
2. Now the user enters a second number, which you store in `variable2` because `variable1` is non-zero.
3. The user then has two options: 1. press the Equals key and perform logic normally, or press another arithmetic key and continue calculating. In the second case, perform the action on your two variables, display the result and store it in `variable1`, and clear the values of `variable2` and `arithmeticProcess`.

Now, you're essentially back in the same place you would be if the user had just started the application, and entered the first number in the calculation. You should be able to continue as normal from here.

Comment: `If lblDisplay.Text = "0" Then
            lblDisplay.Text = ""
        End If

        txtNumber = lblDisplay.Text

        If txtNumber.Contains(".") Then
            If txtNumber.Length > 10 Then
                MessageBox.Show("display shall show no more than 10 digits.")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        ElseIf txtNumber.Length > 9 Then
            MessageBox.Show("display shall show no more than 10 digits.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        txtNumber += "1"
        lblDisplay.Text = txtNumber`

Comment: This is the code for my buttons 0-9, but how can I flow chart the application? What are the steps to take to do this.